# Generating pbkdf2_sha256 hash of a password by means of MySQL

Tags: mysql, hash, sha

I have a bunch of hashed passwords `pbkdf2_sha256$10000$0POUvc6y8M4z$QyldL9qyQO...`. Is it possible to verify them in SQL queries? Don't ask why.

Comment: Why not ask why? Why?

Comment: I can get this hash by means of python, but I have to get it in MySQL.

Comment: And why is that? It is probably impossible to do efficiently in MySQL.

Comment: Trying to use lib_mysqludf_sys module + an external script...

Answer (score 0):

Usually database systems do not support this kind of hash functions on their own. It would be difficult to write the queries anyway, because the password hashes are not searchable. To verify a password with its hash-value following steps are necessary:

1. Search for the row by username (cannot be done by the hash-value).
2. Return the password-hash from the found row.
3. Extract the used salt and the cost factor from the stored password-hash.
4. Build a new hash-value from the entered password with the same salt and cost factor.
5. Compare the stored hash-value and the new calculated one.

That means, you first have to know the stored hash-value, before you can verify the entered password with it. Such a hash function is surely better placed in the development language, than in the database, especially when you later have to switch the algorithm or the cost factor and need backwards compatibility.